# Integral $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x e^{-cx}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$ (possibly using modified Bessel function)?

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

Given $c>0$, can the integral
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x e^{-cx}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx
$$
be expressed in closed form where special functions are allowed?
(I can evaluate it numerically for any given value of $c$. But if possible I'm seeking an expression around $c$, and preferably an expression that I could use in a single cell in a spreadsheet.)

*My attempted solution*:  Let
$x = \cos\theta$.
Then
$$\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x e^{-cx}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx
&= \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{0} \frac{e^{-c\cos\theta} \cos\theta}{\sin\theta} (-\sin\theta) \, d\theta
\\&= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-c\cos\theta} \cos\theta \, d\theta
\end{align*}$$
Now for any integer $n$ we have
$$
  I_n(z) = \int_{0}^{\pi} e^{z\cos\theta} \cos(n\theta) \, d\theta
$$
where $I_n(z)$ is the [modified Bessel function of the first kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html). Putting $n=1$ matches the integrands but not the limits of integration.

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Alpha gives this (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+exp%28c*cos%28x%29%29*cos%28x%29+from+0+to+pi%2F2). Which is a combination of bessel and struve functions. Not sure if that helps you wrt a spreadsheet though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a combination of a modified Bessel function *and something else* since the structure of the integral $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\cos\theta\right)^n\,d\theta$ depends on the parity of $n$. Namely we have

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\cos\theta\right)^{2n}\,d\theta = \frac{\pi}{2\cdot 4^n}\binom{2n}{n},\qquad \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\cos\theta\right)^{2n+1}\,d\theta = \frac{4^n}{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}$$
so

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-cx}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx&=&\int_{0}^{\pi/2}e^{-c\cos\theta}\,d\theta=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n c^n}{n!}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\cos\theta\right)^n\,d\theta\\&=&\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{c^{2n}\binom{2n}{n}}{(2n)!4^n}-\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{c^{2n+1}4^n}{(2n+1)!(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}\\[0.2cm]&=&\frac{\pi}{2}\underbrace{\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{c^{2n}}{4^n n!^2}}_{\text{Bessel}}-\underbrace{\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{c^{2n+1}4^n n!^2}{(2n+1)!^2}}_{\text{Not Bessel}}\end{eqnarray*} $$
and the same method applies to
$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x e^{-cx}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx $, which is just the opposite of the derivative of the last series:

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x e^{-cx}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx = \underbrace{\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{c^{2n}4^n n!^2}{(2n)!(2n+1)!}}_{\text{Not Bessel}}-\frac{\pi}{4}\underbrace{\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{c^{2n+1}}{4^n n!(n+1)!}}_{\text{Bessel}}.$$

Comment: The non-Bessel part is a Struve function: $$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{c^{2n} 4^n n!^2 }}{{(2n)!(2n + 1)!}}}  = \frac{\pi }{2}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\left( {\frac{1}{2}c} \right)^{2n} }}{{\Gamma \big( {n + \frac{3}{2}} \big)\Gamma \left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)}}}  = \frac{\pi }{2}\mathbf{L}_{ - 1} (c)
$$ (cf. http://dlmf.nist.gov/11.2.E2).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is due to @gigo318.
Entering the following into [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20exp%28-c*cos%28theta%29%29*cos%28theta%29%20from%200%20to%20pi%2F2)

```
integrate exp(-c*cos(theta))*cos(theta) from 0 to pi/2
```

yields

```
1/2 π (-BesselI(1, c) + StruveL(-1, c))
```